# underlyingCoreCryptoError(error: -1) while verify signature

Tags: ios, swift, cryptokit

getting error while verifying private key signature using `cryptokit`

What i tried:

```
func signMessage(_ message: String, withPrivateKey privateKey: Data) -> Data {
    do{
        let key = try P256.Signing.PrivateKey(rawRepresentation: privateKey) // here it throws error
        let signature = try key.signature(for: message.data(using: .utf8)!)
        return signature.rawRepresentation
    }catch{
        print(error)
        return Data()
    }
}
```

**Error:** `underlyingCoreCryptoError(error: -1)`

**Additional Info:** message is kind of header token and looks like this

```
eyJhbGciddJFUzI1diIsImtpZdI6IjdXNFQ5dlFRdEMifQ==.eyJpYXQiOjE2Off5MTEwOfksImlzcyI6fjdWUTfQOExRfFMifQ==
```

should i need to trim `message` with `=`?

i am not sure what's wrong with this code but it throws `underlyingCoreCryptoError`.
Suggestion will be thankful.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @mkdavor not yet